# large loop for timing tests gets somehow optimized to nothing?

Tags: c++, optimization, compiler-optimization, timing

I am trying to test a series of libraries for matrix-vector computations. For that I just make a large loop and inside I call the routine I want to time. Very simple.  However I sometimes see that when I increase the level of optimization for the compiler the time drops to zero no matter how large the loop is. See the example below where I try to time a C macro to compute cross products. What is the compiler doing? how can I avoid it but to allow maximum optimization for floating point arithmetics? Thank you in advance

The example below was compiled using g++ 4.7.2 on a computer with an i5 intel processor.
Using optimization level 1 (-O1) it takes 0.35 seconds. For level two or higher it drops down to zero. Remember, I want to time this so I want the computations to actually happen even if, for this simple test, unnecessary.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef double  Vector[3];
#define VecCross(A,assign_op,B,dummy_op,C)              \
(   A[0] assign_op (B[1] * C[2]) - (B[2] * C[1]),       \
    A[1] assign_op (B[2] * C[0]) - (B[0] * C[2]),       \
    A[2] assign_op (B[0] * C[1]) - (B[1] * C[0])        \
)

double get_time(){
  return clock()/(double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}

int main()
{
  unsigned long n = 1000000000u;
  double start;

  {//C macro cross product                                                                                                                                              
    Vector u = {1,0,0};
    Vector v = {1,1,0};
    Vector w = {1.2,1.2,1.2};

    start = get_time();
    for(unsigned long i=0;i<n;i++){
      VecCross (w, =, u, X, v);
    }
    cout << "C macro cross product: " << get_time()-start << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check the generated machine code.

Comment: You never do anything with the result of your computation, so the compiler doesn't bother calculating it.

Comment: @KerrekSB, could you expand on this? how would I do that? and more importantly how it would help me? my final goal is to be able to time how long it takes to do all those many cross products.

Comment: @AlanStokes, thanks. Fine, that was my guess but, how do I disable that behavior but still optimize the single cross product operation itself? I still wanna time this. Any other smarter test suggestion?

Comment: It would help you to check whether you're measuring the right thing. You could add something like `volatile asm("":::"memory");` into your loop to encourage the compiler to not remove the code, but you'll have to check that you're actually executing the desired code.

Comment: @KerrekSB, wow, very interesting. I just used a simple 'asm ("");' before the cross product and then I always got the same timing for all levels of optimization. Do you think this is what I want? did my cross product arithmetic get optimized anyway?

Comment: @Alejandro: I hate to repeat myself, but: check the generated machine code.

Comment: @KerrekSB, I dont really know how to check machine code. I just want a solution to time this, that's all. Also, I found out that if I just leave the asm (""); alone withing the loop (NO cross product!!) it takes the same time!! is this reasonable?

Answer (score 2):

Ask yourself, what does your program actually **do**, in terms of what is visible to the end-user?

It displays the result of a calculation: `get_time()-start`. The contents of your loop have no bearing on the outcome of that calculation, because you never actually use the variables being modified inside the loop.

Therefore, the compiler optimises out the entire loop since it is irrelevant.

One solution is to output the final state of the variables being modified in the loop, as part of your `cout` statement, thus forcing the compiler to compute the loop. However, a smart compiler could also figure out that the loop always calculates the same thing, and it can simply insert the result directly into your `cout` statement, because there's no need to actually calculate it at run-time. As a workaround to this, you could for example require that one of the inputs to the loop be provided at run-time (e.g. read it in from a file, command line argument, `cin`, etc.).

For more (and possibly better) solutions, check out this duplicate thread: [Force compiler to not optimize side-effect-less statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152333/force-compiler-to-not-optimize-side-effect-less-statements)

Comment: Even better solution would be to use `cerr` to print result and redirect stderr to `/dev/null` so that stream cost doesn't affect the profile result (or atleast affect minimum).

Comment: @JBentley, I still get a zero time. Apparently the compiler is "too smart". Any other suggestions?

Comment: @JBentley. The volatile clearly showed different results in my simple C macro case. Things do not work with objects though!!! since c++ checks that arguments are say "Vector" instead of "volatile Vector" something I cannot change since I'm using a library.